# WYSIWG Editor enchancment

Tags: feature-request

There are so many Qs on WA that are about taxonomies, custom post types and terms. Most of these Qs are organizational Qs and need to explain their setup. In most cases they try to do this with text, lists or some custom "-"-tables. A table button for the editor would be a pretty helpful addition.

If you think this might help, please leave an answer and upvote.

---

*Sidenote: As a fact there can be no solution for this Q (exception: SE team member says "feat. will be added"), so i mark the A with the most upvotes as an answer.*

Comment: This feature [has been asked for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-any-markdown-to-create-tables) multiple times at the main Meta Stack Overflow site, maybe it's better to join forces there to ask for support.

Comment: AH, thanks. Didn't know.